# Better logic to check Financial year dates

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I already have a logic to check dates entered are exactly a financial year dates

```
if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(endate.Year))
{
    if (totalDay != 366)
    {
        error("Please make sure start and end dates are financial year dates.<br />E.g.<br /> Start Date:01/07/2012 <br /> End Date :30/06/2013");
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    if (totalDay != 365)
    {
        error("Please make sure start and end Dates are Financial year dates.<br />E.g.<br /> Start Date:01/07/2012 <br /> End Date :30/06/2013");
        return;
    }
}
```

This way I am checking for a dates entered have exactly 1 year difference. But it doesn't check if the user entered exactly startdate 01/07/20XX - endate 30/06/20XX. I can hard code and validate the dates and months and check the difference between the entered years to achieve this but is there a better way I can do it?

Comment: That would really depend on your audience. Different countries have different yearly reporting periods.

Comment: Sure but the financial years dates here are eg: 01/07/2013 -- 30/06/2014. and this application for now, is not used in any other country. But you are right that would be interesting to design one for all countries

Comment: You could include the dates of finanical year in a resource file. For different country, you need to create different resource file.

winform:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3.aspx

webform:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247246(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: But for now I just want to validate dates in this format - 01/07/2XXX - 30/06/2XXX without hard coding the values.

Comment: so are dates allowed to be other than 01/07/20xx and 30/06/20xx but still be a year apart? such as, 01/10/20xx and 30/09/20xx? it seems you really only care about precisely one year difference

Comment: no if that was the case my logic would have partly worked. I want start date -01 start month -07 endate - 30 end month 06 no matter what. But the year can be anything with 1 year difference between the start year and end year. i think I can validate by hardcoding dates, months and checking the diff between the year to b 1, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Assuming this is for parameters to some sort of query, you should consider eliminating all of the unnecessary date portions (month and day) and simply query based on financial year (or fiscal year, whatever you call it). So, perhaps just a dropdown for FY with just the year values.

Comment: @ethorn10: But the calender tool used to select start date and endate are used for other purposes as well. So I have to validate this in my method itself which is supplied with complete dates for start and end

Comment: What @ethorn10 said - Just query for the year-number, and generate the July 1 and June 20 in your code

Comment: Why are you hassling the user to enter dates if you don't actually care about them?  Just let him enter the year.

Comment: How do you set your logic that says that this date range completes a financial year.. One year or 365 days...? Both are different because days depends on the year.. 365 or 366.. Use Timespan to apply it..

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
DateTime starDate = TextToDate(txtStartDate.Text); //01/07/2013
// or startDate = DateTimePicker1.Value;

DateTime endDate = TextToDate(txtEndDate.Text);  //30/06/2014
// or endDate = DatetTimePicker2.Value

DateTime calculatedEndDate = startDate.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
// 01/07/2013 .AddYears(1) ==> 01/07/2014 .AddDays(-1) ==> 30/06/2014

// Note for above line:
//     if you will be using the start date and end date in an sql query
//     remove the call to function AddDays(-1)
//     for display purposes, keep the function AddDays(-1)


if(endDate != calculatedEndDate)
// note: if DateTimePicker is returning time component, then you will need to compare each (year, month and day)
{
    // show error message
}
else
{
    // dates are 1 year apart.
}
```

Alternatively, you can ask the user to enter start date only and then calculate the end date.